# Не работает SELECT COUNT(*) в Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

При выполнении запроса на получение количества записей возникает ошибка

> Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>   The error may involve dataAccess.PhoneRecordMapper.getCountOfRecords-Inline
>   The error occurred while setting parameters
>   Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Сам запрос, в котором возникает ошибка(при чем при выполнении запроса на сервере, а не через код - все работает нормально)

```
<select id="getCountOfRecords" resultType="java.lang.Integer" parameterType="hashmap">
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM t_call
        LEFT JOIN t_event
        ON t_call.ID_CALL = t_event.CALL_ID
</select>

<resultMap type="phoneRecord" id="phoneRecordMap">
        <id property="recordId" column="RECORD_ID"/>
        <result property="recordId" column="RECORD_ID"/>
        <result property="recordEventId" column="RECORD_EVENT_ID"/>
        <result property="recordDate" column="RECORD_DATE"/>
        <result property="caller" column="CALLER"/>
        <result property="reciever" column="RECIEVER"/>
        <result property="callId" column="CALL_ID"/>
        <result property="idCall" column="ID_CALL"/>
</resultMap>
```

метод в интерфейсе:

```
public int getCountOfRecords(HashMap<String, Object> param);
```

Если доставать через код просто все записи, тогда все ок, и записи достаются.
Может кто то подсказать в чем может быть проблема?
Записи достаю в Struts экшене.

Comment: у вас parameterType="hashmap". может в этом дело?

Comment: ну в этом не может быть проблемы.
В других запросах тоже использовал, и проблем не было.

Comment: @Mikhail48 уберите parameterType из xml + проверьте название метода и сигнатуру метода в интерфейсе.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Так то да, оно работает. Но в дальнейшем в сам запрос добавится WHERE блок, и для него я передаю значения через hashMap.
И вот в таком случае - все крашится.

Comment: какой метод в интерфейсе? дополните вопрос

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov дополнил.

Comment: трудно сказать, видимо, он ожидает что в xml как то будет задействован параметр, который был передан в метод. попробуйте дописать в конце запроса where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос `count` с параметрами в `mybatis` выглядит следующим образом:

```
 <select id="countByExample" parameterType="ru.izebit.model.MySuperModelExample"
        resultType="java.lang.Integer">
    select count(*) from my_super_table
    <if test="_parameter != null">
        <include refid="Example_Where_Clause"/>
    </if>
</select>
```

где `MySuperModelExample` - это объект содержащий параметры запроса. Его писать в ручную не обязательно, он генерируется `maven` плагином `mybatis-generator-maven-plugin`

Comment: А если без плагина?
Мне просто нельзя использовать его.(